Is there a way of using http library such as python “Request” to scrape a website that requires logging in?
I don’t ask how to login to the website. I ask how to let the destination website (which require an user login) somehow thinks that I am an user in an already-log-in state (but in-fact I’m in the terminal using something like Get in python Requests targeting that website) let me get the html response just like a normal user. Can I login via Chrome then grab some piece of unique information identified me as this user then use this info in the terminal to fake the user accessing the website? Tell me what is it info? I know an application in my country they grab something called spc_f from the web cookie they logged in then they can fake that user login identity to access that web with different platform (They does need to to emulate the login but with that spc_f cookie grab, the website doesn’t ask for a 2 steps verification as usual)

You probably want to save the cookies from where you're logged in, and reuse them in your script.

That is literally impossible to answer. Different webpages use different authentication mechanisms, often very different. The relevant data may be stored in cookies, or headers, or even body. Moreover it may have expiration date (e.g. JWT), in which case even if you grab it, it won't help you for long. I don't know what spc_f is, but it sounds like something very custom. Sorry, but this is a case-by-case work. And it would be better to learn how to log in and emulate that process. Also, completely unrelated to requests lib - it will let you pass any information you want to the server.

I'm guessing spc_f is the name of the cookie which that particular site uses.

Use the Selenium bindings for python to log in not chrome?
